# Alert Dialog builder coming black color background in android

Tags: android

I am using alert dialog builder in application. I have checked in api level16 getting black color background for dialog but not in api level 8.Can anybody tell how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/dark_blue">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_wishlist_title" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button android:id="@+id/phoneButton" android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/phone_button" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/emailButton" android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/email_buton" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/accountButton" android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="@string/account_button" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Inflate this layout in any activity where you want to set the alert dialog.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(VMAdjustFrame.this);
promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.wishlist_save_prompt, null);
alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VMAdjustFrame.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.show();
```